# Возможно ли использовать WordPress и CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

Есть сайт на WordPress (основной) и сайт пару страниц на CodeIgniter. Возможно ли их использовать в корне хостинга, когда в основном используется сайт WordPress (типа: vashsite/), а сайт на CodeIgniterзакинуть в папку и использовать (типа: vashsite/cifolder/)

Извините, что так плохо сформулировал.

Возможно ли написать специальный .htaccess файл для редиректа на WordPress или CodeIgniter в зависимости от url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если установите в поддиректорию, то вполне. Точно так же в поддиректорию вы можете установить в принципе любую CMS/Framework и она тоже будет работать. По типу `site.com/` и поддиректория `site.com/somefolder/`